# Table/Graph Report Builder 3.0 Graph doesnt want to stay in position

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I've the following problem.
I wanna build a report with two bar graphs on the on the left side. The Graph should be above each other. On the other side of the page I wanna have two thin tables next to each other.

Now I have the problem that the second graph won't stay straight under the first graph. It always moves down to the position of the end of the tables If I've saved it.

How can I get the graph to stay in the position I placed in the Report builder.

Would be really nice if someone has answer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the Graphs inside a rectangle.

That should fix the problem.

Have a look at [Report Design Tips (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714051.aspx)

and more specifically the section on **Designing Reports** and **Controlling the Rendering of Report Items on the Report Page**